# issue when profiling JVM Thread Pool ( under Spring intégration + Weblogic )

Tags: profiling, threadpool, spring-integration, weblogic11g, jvm-hotspot

I have to maintain an application under Spring Integration (SI) and Weblogic 11g (with no workmanager configuration).

When I'm testing the performance on this application with JProfiler, I see a strange behavior regarding the threads : http://postimg.org/image/60w21njp3/

1. a thread pool with (approximatively) 160 threads
2. threads which are always created and destroyed

Under Spring, we use a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor named "guillaume" and injected into a ListenerContainer like this :

```
<bean id="listenersExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
     <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="guillaume-" />
     <property name="daemon" value="true" />
</bean>
```

With :

```
<bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="..." />
    <property name="destination" ref="..." />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="..." />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="listenersExecutor" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="..." />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="..." />
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="..." />
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="..." />
</bean>
```

**My question**

I quote Javadoc on SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor :

> TaskExecutor implementation that fires up a new Thread for each task, executing it asynchronously.

Who created the threadpool into JVM named "guillaume" ? not Spring ? Weblogic ?

Even if I don't have any activities with the SI, are there threads which are created and destroyed ?

Let me know if you need any additional informations.
Thanks.

Comment: I am confused by your question "who created...?" - you defined it above. You need to show more configuration (actual values for the container properties). The listener container will use a thread per consumer.

Comment: Thx, but as I said, the application use an SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor which doesn't create a Threadpool (because this implementation creates  a new thread for each task). I don't understand which of Spring or Weblogic creates this Treadpool.

Comment: The fact they are called `guillaume-xx` means they came from the `TE`; I don't know why they show as `[Pooled Thread]` in your screen shot, but they clearly are not in a pool, as evidenced by the fact you have one called `...-2607`. The others, I suspect are your concurrent consumers (each consumer generally uses a long-lived thread). Turn on `TRACE` debugging and all should become clear.